# How do i split the input into chunks of six entries each using bash?

Tags: bash

This is the script which i run to output the raw data of data_tripwire.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

    LOG=/var/log/syslog-ng/svrs/sec2tes1

for count in 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
do
    MONTH=`date -d"$count month ago" +"%Y-%m"`

    CBS=`bzcat $LOG/$MONTH*.log.bz2|grep 10.55.22.41 |sort|uniq | wc -l`
    echo $CBS >> /home/secmgr/attmrms1/data_tripwire1.sh
done

for count in 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
do
    MONTH=`date -d"$count month ago" +"%Y-%m"`

    GFS=`bzcat $LOG/$MONTH*.log.bz2|grep 10.55.22.31 |sort|uniq | wc -l`
    echo $GFS >> /home/secmgr/attmrms1/data_tripwire1.sh
done

for count in 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
do
    MONTH=`date -d"$count month ago" +"%Y-%m"`

    HR1=`bzcat $LOG/$MONTH*.log.bz2|grep 10.55.10.1 |sort|uniq | wc -l `
    echo $HR1 >> /home/secmgr/attmrms1/data_tripwire1.sh
done


for count in 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
do
    MONTH=`date -d"$count month ago" +"%Y-%m"`

    HR2=`bzcat $LOG/$MONTH*.log.bz2|grep 10.55.21.12 |sort|uniq | wc -l`
    echo $HR2 >> /home/secmgr/attmrms1/data_tripwire1.sh
done

for count in 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
do
    MONTH=`date -d"$count month ago" +"%Y-%m"`

    PAYROLL=`bzcat $LOG/$MONTH*.log.bz2|grep 10.55.21.18 |sort|uniq | wc -l`
    echo $PAYROLL >> /home/secmgr/attmrms1/data_tripwire1.sh

done

for count in 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
do
    MONTH=`date -d"$count month ago" +"%Y-%m"`

    INCV=`bzcat $LOG/$MONTH*.log.bz2|grep 10.55.22.71 |sort|uniq | wc -l`
    echo $INCV >> /home/secmgr/attmrms1/data_tripwire1.sh
done
```

data_tripwire.sh

```
91
58
54
108
52
18
8
81
103
110
129
137
84
15
14
18
11
17
12
6
1
28
6
14
8
8
0
0
28
24
25
23
21
13
9
4
18
17
18
30
13
3
```

I want to do the first 6 entries(91,58,54,108,52,18) from the output above. Then it will break out of the loop.After that it will continue for the next 6 entries.Then it will break out of the loop again....

The problem now is that it reads all the 42 numbers without breaking out of the loop.

This is the output of the table

```
Tripwire

Month   CBS     GFS      HR     HR         Payroll   INCV 
        cb2db1  gfs2db1 hr2web1 hrm2db1   hrm2db1a   incv2svr1 
2013-07 85      76      12      28        26          4 
2013-08 58      103     18      6         24         18 
2013-09 54      110     11      14        25         17 
2013-10 108     129     17      8         23         18 
2013-11 52      137     12      8         21         30 
2013-12 18      84      6       0         13         13 
2014-01 8       16      1       0         9           3
```

The problem now is that it read the total 42 numbers from 85...3
I want to make a loop which run from july till jan for one server.Then it will do the average mean and standard deviation calculation which is already done below.
After that done, it will continue the next cycle of 6 numbers for the next server and it will do the same like initial cycle.Assistance is required for the for loops which has break and continue in it or any simpler.

This is my standard deviation calculation

```
count=0         # Number of data points; global.
SC=3            # Scale to be used by bc. three decimal places.
E_DATAFILE=90   # Data file error

## ----------------- Set data file ---------------------

if [ ! -z "$1" ]  # Specify filename as cmd-line arg?
then
  datafile="$1" #  ASCII text file,
else            #+ one (numerical) data point per line!
  datafile=/home/secmgr/attmrms1/data_tripwire1.sh
fi              #  See example data file, below.

if [ ! -e "$datafile" ]
then
  echo "\""$datafile"\" does not exist!"
  exit $E_DATAFILE
fi
```

Calculate the mean

```
arith_mean ()
{
  local rt=0         # Running total.
  local am=0         # Arithmetic mean.
  local ct=0         # Number of data points.

  while read value   # Read one data point at a time.
  do
    rt=$(echo "scale=$SC; $rt + $value" | bc)
    (( ct++ ))
  done

  am=$(echo "scale=$SC; $rt / $ct" | bc)

  echo $am; return $ct   # This function "returns" TWO values!
  #  Caution: This little trick will not work if $ct > 255!
  #  To handle a larger number of data points,
  #+ simply comment out the "return $ct" above.
} <"$datafile"   # Feed in data file.

sd ()
{
  mean1=$1  # Arithmetic mean (passed to function).
  n=$2      # How many data points.
  sum2=0    # Sum of squared differences ("variance").
  avg2=0    # Average of $sum2.

sdev=0    # Standard Deviation.

  while read value   # Read one line at a time.
  do
    diff=$(echo "scale=$SC; $mean1 - $value" | bc)
    # Difference between arith. mean and data point.
    dif2=$(echo "scale=$SC; $diff * $diff" | bc) # Squared.
    sum2=$(echo "scale=$SC; $sum2 + $dif2" | bc) # Sum of squares.
  done

    avg2=$(echo "scale=$SC; $sum2 / $n" | bc)  # Avg. of sum of squares.
    sdev=$(echo "scale=$SC; sqrt($avg2)" | bc) # Square root =
    echo $sdev                                 # Standard Deviation.

} <"$datafile"   # Rewinds data file.
```

Showing the output

```
mean=$(arith_mean); count=$?   # Two returns from function!
std_dev=$(sd $mean $count)

echo
echo "<tr><th>Servers</th><th>"Number of data points in \"$datafile"\"</th> <th>Arithmetic mean (average)</th><th>Standard Deviation</th></tr>" >> $HTML
echo "<tr><td>cb2db1<td>$count<td>$mean<td>$std_dev</tr>" >> $HTML
echo "<tr><td>gfs2db1<td>$count<td>$mean<td>$std_dev</tr>" >> $HTML
echo "<tr><td>hr2web1<td>$count<td>$mean<td>$std_dev</tr>" >> $HTML
echo "<tr><td>hrm2db1<td>$count<td>$mean<td>$std_dev</tr>" >> $HTML
echo "<tr><td>hrm2db1a<td>$count<td>$mean<td>$std_dev</tr>" >> $HTML
echo "<tr><td>incv21svr1<td>$count<td>$mean<td>$std_dev</tr>" >> $HTML

echo
```

I want to split the input into chunks of six entries each with the arithmetic mean and the sd of the entries 1..6, then of the entries 7..12, then of 13..18 etc.

This is the output of the table i want.

```
Tripwire

Month   CBS     GFS      HR     HR         Payroll   INCV 
        cb2db1  gfs2db1 hr2web1 hrm2db1   hrm2db1a   incv2svr1 
2013-07 85      76      12      28        26          4 
2013-08 58      103     18      6         24         18 
2013-09 54      110     11      14        25         17 
2013-10 108     129     17      8         23         18 
2013-11 52      137     12      8         21         30 
2013-12 18      84      6       0         13         13 
2014-01 8       16      1       0         9           3
*Standard
deviation
(7mths)  31.172   35.559    5.248  8.935  5.799    8.580 
* Mean
(7mths) 54.428  94.285   11.142 9.142  20.285   14.714
```

Comment: Does it really work to put the redirection outside the function definition, instead of in the `while read` loop inside the function?

Comment: Read the input outside the functions, and put it in an array. After every 6 lines, call your functions with the array as the argument. Then clear the array and continue looping.

Comment: Are you trying to split your input into chunks of six entries each?  So you want to get the arithmetic mean and the sd of the entries 1..6, then of the entries 7..12, then of 13..18 etc.?

Comment: The `bash` idiom for supplying a default parameter value is `datafile=${1:-/home/secmgr/attmrms1/data_tripwire1.sh}`.

Comment: @Alfe yes you are right

Comment: Without modifying your code too much, I'll recommend using awk as input instead of straight read from datafile. The input will look like `< (awk -v block=$i 'NR > (block - 1)  && NR < (6 * block + 1) {print}' $datafile)` and in your `main` you create a loop setting `i` from `1` to `$(( $(wc -l $datafile) / 6 ))`.

Comment: @alvits where do i put that ?

Comment: I'll write it below and let me know how it works out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
paste - - - - - - < data_tripwire.sh | while read -a values; do
    # values is an array with 6 values
    # ${values[0]} .. ${values[5]}
    arith_mean "${values[@]}"
done
```

This means you have to rewrite your function so they don't use `read`: change

```
while read value
```

to

```
for value in "$@"
```

---

@Matt, yes change both functions to iterate over arguments instead of reading from stdin. Then, you will pass the data file (now called "data_tripwire1.sh" (terrible file extension for data, use .txt or .dat)) into `paste` to reformat the data so that the first 6 values now form the first row. Read the line into the array `values` (using `read -a values`) and invoke the functions :

```
arith_mean () {
    local sum=$(IFS=+; echo "$*")
    echo "scale=$SC; ($sum)/$#" | bc
}
sd () {
    local mean=$1
    shift
    local sum2=0
    for i in "$@"; do
        sum2=$(echo "scale=$SC; $sum2 + ($mean-$i)^2" | bc)
    done
    echo "scale=$SC; sqrt($sum2/$#)"|bc
}

paste - - - - - - < data_tripwire1.sh | while read -a values; do
    mean=$(arith_mean "${values[@]}")
    sd=$(sd $mean "${values[@]}")
    echo "${values[@]} $mean $sd"
done | column -t
```

```
91  58  54   108  52   18   63.500  29.038
8   81  103  110  129  137  94.666  42.765
84  15  14   18   11   17   26.500  25.811
12  6   1    28   6    14   11.166  8.648
8   8   0    0    28   24   11.333  10.934
25  23  21   13   9    4    15.833  7.711
18  17  18   30   13   3    16.500  7.973
```

Note you don't need to return a fancy value from the functions: you know how many points you pass in.

Comment: Where do i paste the while loop ? i have to rewrite for both mean and standard deviation function?

Comment: where do i declare the values for the arrays

Comment: I guess it should be `data_tripwire.sh | paste - - - - - - | while read -a  values; do` ...

Comment: Is `data_tripwire.sh` a script you call which then outputs the list of numbers you've shown in your question?  Or is this file just a text file containing these numbers?  Your question isn't clear about that; I guess it is the first, Glenn seems to assume the latter.

Answer (score 0):

The functions will now be able to only read 6 items in datafile.

```
arith_mean ()
{
  local rt=0         # Running total.
  local am=0         # Arithmetic mean.
  local ct=0         # Number of data points.

  while read value   # Read one data point at a time.
  do
    rt=$(echo "scale=$SC; $rt + $value" | bc)
    (( ct++ ))
  done

  am=$(echo "scale=$SC; $rt / $ct" | bc)

  echo $am; return $ct   # This function "returns" TWO values!
  #  Caution: This little trick will not work if $ct > 255!
  #  To handle a larger number of data points,
  #+ simply comment out the "return $ct" above.
} <(awk -v block=$i 'NR > (6* (block - 1)) && NR < (6 * block + 1) {print}' "$datafile")   # Feed in data file.

sd ()
{
  mean1=$1  # Arithmetic mean (passed to function).
  n=$2      # How many data points.
  sum2=0    # Sum of squared differences ("variance").
  avg2=0    # Average of $sum2.

sdev=0    # Standard Deviation.

  while read value   # Read one line at a time.
  do
    diff=$(echo "scale=$SC; $mean1 - $value" | bc)
    # Difference between arith. mean and data point.
    dif2=$(echo "scale=$SC; $diff * $diff" | bc) # Squared.
    sum2=$(echo "scale=$SC; $sum2 + $dif2" | bc) # Sum of squares.
  done

    avg2=$(echo "scale=$SC; $sum2 / $n" | bc)  # Avg. of sum of squares.
    sdev=$(echo "scale=$SC; sqrt($avg2)" | bc) # Square root =
    echo $sdev                                 # Standard Deviation.

} <(awk -v block=$i 'NR > (6 * (block - 1)) && NR < (6 * block + 1) {print}' "$datafile")   # Rewinds data file.
```

From main you will need to set your blocks to read.

```
for((i=1; i <= $(( $(wc -l $datafile | sed 's/[A-Za-z \/]*//g') / 6 )); i++))
do
    mean=$(arith_mean); count=$?   # Two returns from function!
    std_dev=$(sd $mean $count)
done
```

Of course it is better to move the `wc -l` outside of the loop for faster execution. But you get the idea.

The syntax error occured between `<` and `(` due to space. There shouldn't be a space between them. Sorry for the typo.

`cat <(awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd)` works.

`cat < (awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd)` syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: i want to read the input into 6 entries each , after that it will break the loop and then continue reading the next 6 ..

Comment: the function u wrote only reads 6 items but not the next 6 items and the subsequent 6 ..

Comment: ./TripwireReview_Version3.sh: line 110: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[secmgr@sec2log1 attmrms1]$./TripwireReview_Version3.sh: line 110: `} < (awk -v block=$i 'NR > (block - 1) && NR < (6 * block + 1) {print}' "$datafile")   # Feed in data file.'

Comment: There shouldn't be an extra space between `<` and `(`. I'll fix the typo. The function will read 6 items in multiple of `i`.

Comment: this isnt what i want

Answer (score 0):

Based on Glenn's answer I propose this which needs very little changes to the original:

```
paste - - - - - - < data_tripwire.sh | while read -a values
  do 
    for value in "${values[@]}"
    do
      echo "$value"
    done | arith_mean
    for value in "${values[@]}"
    do
      echo "$value"
    done | sd
  done
```

You can type (or copy & paste) this code *directly* in an interactive shell.  It should work out of the box.  Of course, this is not feasible if you intend to use this often, so you can put that code into a text file, make that executable and call that text file as a shell script.  In this case you should add `#!/bin/bash` as first line in that file.

Credit to Glenn Jackman for the use of `paste - - - - - -` which is the real solution I'd say.

Comment: data_tripwire.sh consists of the raw data from another script which i run .. scroll to the top ..

Comment: It is very unusual to name a file containing the output of another call something like `*.sh`.  Typically such names (i. e. that suffix) is used for shell scripts which are _programs_, not data.  But anyway, if this file does not _generate_ the data upon being called but _contains_ the data, then I'll have to adjust my solution.  Concerning your question where to put that code, I'll clarify that in the answer.  So please see my updated answer.

Comment: i already changed my file to data_tripwire.txt. Thanks for the tip